# How to use "adjustPan" and "adjustResize" together

Tags: android, window-soft-input-mode

I am facing a weired issue. i have two fragments in a single activity. One is a login Fragement . I have two edit text in this fragment. Some devices this filed is hiding by soft keyaboard  i specified adjustPan in my manifest and this is working fine

When user clicking a button on LoginFragment i am opening another fragment named forgetpassword . This is a webview and url is loading from a remote server. But the textfield in html is hide by softkeyboard. So i tried using adjustResize and it is working fine. But my editText widget in loginfragment is hide by keyboard.

How can i achieve both flags in my activity.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by setting `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` programmatically.

Use the following code to set `ajustPan` when the current Fragment is your `LoginFragment`:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

And use the following code to set `ajustResize` when the current Fragment is your `webview  Fragment`:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: When placing adjust pan in the manifest this works correctly but when trying to place both flags in a fragment with flags like this        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN); it does not.

Comment: @DougRay They should not be combined together, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN

Answer (score 0):

`adjustResize`and`adjustPan` can not be combined with each other. They are different default actions for preventing soft input from covering input field. As indicated in the comment for `WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN`

```
    /** Adjustment option for {@link #softInputMode}: set to allow the
     * window to be resized when an input
     * method is shown, so that its contents are not covered by the input
     * method.  This can <em>not</em> be combined with
     * {@link #SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN}; if
     * neither of these are set, then the system will try to pick one or
     * the other depending on the contents of the window. If the window's
     * layout parameter flags include {@link #FLAG_FULLSCREEN}, this
     * value for {@link #softInputMode} will be ignored; the window will
     * not resize, but will stay fullscreen.
     */
    public static final int SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE = 0x10;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem by setting `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` programmatically.
Also, in the `listview` add `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"`